# command line argument in js file for mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am running a js script to work on mongodb as

```
mongo localhost:27017/dbname mongodump_isp.js
```

In the mongodump_isp.js file, I am doing at the very beginning

```
conn= new Mongo();
db=conn.getDb("dbname");
```

I have to again provide the database name inside the js file. How can I provide that dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `conn` part is not necessary but you can just set the "database" name like this:

```
var db = db.getSiblingDB("dbname");
```

And then all references to `db` afterwards will use that database, or you can set another variable to another db connection

But if what you are talking about is specifying the `db` value on the command line, then you **do not** need any extra lines in your code as the value of `db` is already set to what you specified.

Comment: I want to use dbname ascommand line arugument. here everytime I change the dbname , I have to again change in in the code.

Comment: @prashantas The default value of `db` **is** what you specify on the command line when you connect. The only point of altering this with a JavaScript file is to use another database than what you connect to. See the edited details.